# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: vendor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postman

I am trying to make a post using Postman on my Rails app and I get an issue saying:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: vendor
Did you mean?  vendor_data
               action
               quote_type
               controller):
```

This is my `controller` file where the params are called:

```
def create_vendor_params
    params.require(:vendor).permit(
      :vendor_id, :quote_type, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_type, :phone, :request_type, :address1, :address_city, :address_state, :address_zip, :DOB
    )
  end
```

And this is the data I am sending from Postman. Now I am not sure if it's because `renter_data` it's nested and on my `params permit`:

```
{
    "vendor_id": 2,
    "quote_type": "renter",
    "renter_data": {
        "first_name":"Tony",
        "last_name":"Stark",
        "email":"tony@starkindustries",
        "phone_type":"mobile",
        "phone":"6504881234",
        "request_type":"renter",
        "address1":"123 Main Street",
        "address_city":"Palo Alto",
        "address_state":"CA",
        "address_zip":"94301",
        "DOB":"1990-07-22"
    }
}
```

Is this issue because of nested data inside `renter_data`? And if it is, how can I nest it?

### EDIT

When I make the post I see an empty object at the end of the request:

```
Processing by Api::V2::LeadController#create as */*
      Parameters: {"vendor_id"=>2, "quote_type"=>"renter", "renter_data"=>{"first_name"=>"Tony", "last_name"=>"Stark", "email"=>"tony@starkindustries", "phone_type"=>"mobile", "phone"=>"6504881234", "request_type"=>"renter", "address1"=>"123 Main Street", "address_city"=>"Palo Alto", "address_state"=>"CA", "address_zip"=>"94301", "DOB"=>"1990-07-22"}, "vendor"=>{} <---HERE }
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems: First, the strong params expect the input to be nested under `vendor`. Second, the strong params do not expect a nested `renter_data` hash.

To fix this in your query change the structure of the request data to:

```
{
  "vendor": {
    "vendor_id": 2,
    "quote_type": "renter",
    "first_name":"Tony",
    "last_name":"Stark",
    "email":"tony@starkindustries",
    "phone_type":"mobile",
    "phone":"6504881234",
    "request_type":"renter",
    "address1":"123 Main Street",
    "address_city":"Palo Alto",
    "address_state":"CA",
    "address_zip":"94301",
    "DOB":"1990-07-22"
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the nested `renter_data` hash then you have to change the strong params like Paarth Agrawal already suggested. But then you still need to nest everything under `vendor`.

Comment: YES!!!! I wasn't wrapping my hash on to vendor. I was sending it without it. Yes I still need the nested params with renter_data. And so now, it makes sense what Paarth Agrawal said. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the concept of nested strong params in create_vender_params function you have to add more permitted params

```
params.require(:vendor).permit(
  :vendor_id, :quote_type, renter_Data: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_type, :phone, :request_type, :address1, :address_city, :address_state, :address_zip, :DOB])
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work. It still says this message:

`*** ActionController::ParameterMissing Exception: param is missing or the value is empty: vendor
Did you mean?  vendor_id
               vendor_data
               action
               quote_type`

Answer (score 1):

vendor_table has some fields `vendor_id, quote_type, first_name, last_name, email,phone_type,phone, request_type, address1,address_city,address_state, address_zip,DOB`.

```
def create_vendor_params
 params.require(:vendor).permit(
  :vendor_id, :quote_type, :first_name, :last_name, :email, 
  :phone_type,:phone, :request_type, :address1, :address_city, 
  :address_state,:address_zip, :DOB)
end
```

```
 "vendor": {
    "vendor_id": 2,
    "quote_type": "renter",
    "first_name":"Tony",
    "last_name":"Stark",
    "email":"tony@starkindustries",
    "phone_type":"mobile",
    "phone":"6504881234",
    "request_type":"renter",
    "address1":"123 Main Street",
    "address_city":"Palo Alto",
    "address_state":"CA",
    "address_zip":"94301",
    "DOB":"1990-07-22"
  }
```

```
def create 
 @vendor = Vendor.new(create_vendor_params)
 if @vendor.save
    render json: {'Success' }
 else
    render json: {error: @vendor.errors}
 end
end
```

Comment: Indeed this worked fine, Although I just needed to wrap it on the vendor hash, and I was sending it without it.

Comment: Yep, goodluck !